# FastifyError [Error]: Failed building the validation schema for POST

Tags: node.js, typescript, fastify

I am writing a web app with `fastify` in `typescript`. I have generated the project using `fastify-cli`.

```
fastify generate --lang=ts try-fastify-typescript
```

I have used `@sinclair/typebox` for schema validation. But I am getting the below error when running the app `npm start`.

> FastifyError [Error]: Failed building the validation schema for POST:
> /user, due to error strict mode: unknown keyword: "kind"
> at Boot. (/Volumes/Segate Backup Plus Drive/projects/javascript/try-fastify-typescript/node_modules/fastify/lib/route.js:309:21)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28)
> at Boot.emit (events.js:412:35)
> at /Volumes/Segate Backup Plus Drive/projects/javascript/try-fastify-typescript/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:160:12
> at /Volumes/Segate Backup Plus Drive/projects/javascript/try-fastify-typescript/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:276:7
> at done (/Volumes/Segate Backup Plus Drive/projects/javascript/try-fastify-typescript/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:201:5)
> at check (/Volumes/Segate Backup Plus Drive/projects/javascript/try-fastify-typescript/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:225:9)
> at internal/process/task_queues.js:141:7
> at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (async_hooks.js:197:9)
> at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (internal/process/task_queues.js:138:8) {   code:
> 'FST_ERR_SCH_VALIDATION_BUILD',   statusCode: 500 }

Below is my code.

```
import { FastifyPluginAsync, RouteShorthandOptions } from 'fastify';
import { Static, Type } from '@sinclair/typebox';

const User = Type.Object({
  name: Type.String(),
  mail: Type.Optional(Type.String({ format: "email" })),
});
type UserType = Static<typeof User>;
const reqOpts: RouteShorthandOptions = {
  schema: {
    body: User
  }
};
interface GetUserRequest {
  Body: UserType,
  Reply: UserType
}

const root: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify, opts): Promise<void> => {
  fastify.get('/', async function (request, reply) {
    return { root: true }
  });

  fastify.post<GetUserRequest>('/user', reqOpts, async(request, reply)=> {
    request.log.info("User Name: " + request.body.name);
    request.log.info("User Mail: " + request.body.mail);

    return {...request.body};
  });
}

export default root;
```

Adding the full code repository [here](https://github.com/sibu-github/try-fastify-typescript).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, injecting a `Type.Union` with a nested `Type.Null` solved the issue for me.

Union and Null types documentation can be found in [Typebox standard types](https://github.com/sinclairzx81/typebox/blob/master/readme.md#types-standard).

#### type fix

```js
const User = Type.Object({
  mail: Type.Optional(Type.Union([Type.String({ format: "email" }), Type.Null()])),
  name: Type.String(),
});
```

#### updated solution

```js
import { FastifyPluginAsync, RouteShorthandOptions } from 'fastify';
import { Static, Type } from '@sinclair/typebox';

const User = Type.Object({
  mail: Type.Optional(Type.Union([Type.String({ format: "email" }), Type.Null()])),
  name: Type.String(),
});

type UserType = Static<typeof User>;

const reqOpts: RouteShorthandOptions = {
  schema: {
    body: User
  }
};

interface GetUserRequest {
  Body: UserType,
  Reply: UserType
}

const root: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify, opts): Promise<void> => {
  fastify.get('/', async function (request, reply) {
    return { root: true }
  });

  fastify.post<GetUserRequest>('/user', reqOpts, async(request, reply)=> {
    request.log.info("User Name: " + request.body.name);
    request.log.info("User Mail: " + request.body.mail);

    return { ...request.body };
  });
}

export default root;
```